# Is it possible to create custom functions when use sqlite in cakephp

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, cakephp, tdd

I need to create a custom function silimar with mysql. But this must be in sqlite to run tdd.

I have not found how to do this in documentation or in code structure.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.sqlitecreatefunction.php

Thanks.

Comment: are there any reasons why you don't use SQLlite datasource in CakePHP ?

Comment: Not that I know, or I do not understant your question. I always use to work with TDD.

Answer (score 1):

You can get PDO connection with something like this

```
$pdo = $this->SomeModel->getDataSource()->getConnection();
```

And then use your reference.